# does java provide a built-in static String.Compare method?

Tags: java, string, static, compare

when comparing strings I prefer not to rely on instance methods lest the string on which the method is called happens to be null. In .NET I just use the static String.Compare(string, string, bool) method. does java provide a similar built-in "null-safe" string compare utility or do I have to implement my own?

Comment: libraries have that. there is an apache StringUtils I think, and android has TextUtils

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, JDK does not contain such utility. However there are several external libraries that do that. For example `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` provides null-safe `equals(String, String)` and `equalsIgnoreCase(String, String)`. Guava has similar utilities too.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/)' [`StringUtils.equals()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#line.655) does it this way:

```
public static boolean equals(String str1, String str2) {
    return str1 == null ? str2 == null : str1.equals(str2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

String **does** offer a [compareTo method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29), which is anyway not null-safe (i.e. you need to check for null value before actually calling the comapreTo method on the object).

What you can do is write your own Comparator like this

```
class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1 != null) {
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        } else {
            if (s2 == null) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
    }
```

To verify the property just do:

```
Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<String>();
System.out.println(comp.compare(s1, s2);
```

I *didn't* actually test the code, so take it as a general example.
The benefit is that, even though you need to check for null value anyway, you can write it once and use it several times.

You can also take a look at [a built in Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) inside the String class.

Comment: Yes, I find myself adding this type of code to every new project. Seems like there ought to be a `Strings.compare(left, right)` to handle the null check

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is no, you have probably to check it before

```
if(myString != null && myString.equals("string")) {
    // do something
}
```

[Here some more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920525/how-to-check-a-string-against-null-in-java)

As others pointed out Apache Commons has this, and also Spring:

[StringUtils.hasLength()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#hasLength%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
if(StringUtils.hasLength(myString)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If one of the strings to compare is a constant than you can use `equals` as it handles `null`.

```
if("string".equals(mystring)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you have 2 variables then you can write your own static method:

```
public static boolean stringEquals(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1 == null) {
        return s2 == null;
    }
    return s1.equals(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question here
[How to simplify a null-safe compareTo() implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481813/how-to-simplify-a-null-safe-compareto-implementation)

which sagely advises to use the Apache Commons `ObjectUtils` class

```
result = ObjectUtils.compare(left, right);
```

Answer (score -2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

There is the compare to which returns an int.  There is also equals which 
returns a boolean.  If you have a string instance it should be able to 
execute. If you pass instance.equals(null) it will return false.  if your 
instance is null then you will get a null pointer.

```
public class App
{

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String myString = "test";

    if(myString.equals(null))
    {
        System.out.println("Its NUll");
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("Not Equal");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: -1: The question was about a **static**, null-safe built-in method to compare Strings, not how to compare Strings.