# Android cannot find string if its null

Tags: java, android, string, email, null

I want to send Emails using android intent. Every thing is working well except when choosing email app to send email with, in the send to field getting null value, although I check for null values but seems I cannot detect when a string is null. Can anybody help me solve this.

```
if (emailAddress[0]!=null && !emailAddress[0].isEmpty()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddress);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.email_sub));
                // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

Comment: I don't think the `!emailAddress[0].isEmpty()` is necessary... I could be wrong though...

Comment: use this .. public static boolean isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnlyByJava(  
   final String string)  
{  
   return string != null && !string.isEmpty() && !string.trim().isEmpty();  
}

Answer (score 2):

Check the String with **equals()** or **equalsingorecase();**

```
String[]  emailAddress = new String[10]; 

          emailAddress[0]="asdfasdfasdfasdf";

          if (emailAddress[0]!=null && !emailAddress[0].isEmpty())
          {
              System.err.println("asddddddd  " +emailAddress[0] );
          }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920525/how-to-check-a-string-against-null-in-java have a look at this

Answer (score 2):

try to use this syntax its detect null and empty string

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(emailAddress[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence str)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method to detect if `String` is empty or null

Answer (score 0):

TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence char) is used for null String if it don't work then check if(emailAddress != null) because emailAddress[0] position value is null then your array is also null.

Answer (score 0):

it might help you..

you can use any from below 2

```
if (emailAddress[0].toString().equals(""))
```

or

```
if (emailAddress[0].toString().length() > 0)
```

Comment: .toString() was the part that was making all the problems.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The string may not be null. AFAIK Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL takes String array as second argument.

Try this.

```
String[] addressArray = {"add1@mail.com", "a2@mail.com"};

//some lines...

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addressArray);
```

Comment: The OP is passing a `String[]` as the second parameter.

Comment: @jprofit My bad. I guess I expected to see emailAddresses or emailAdressArray