# Comparing two string in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, cursor

I have a method which retrieves rows from an sqlite database and returns them in a cursor.I am retreiving values from the query ok as shown below.

```
    private void checkWatchList() {
    Log.i("watch list", "watch list started");
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = dbhandler.getAlerts();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.i("watch list", "checked");

            String share_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_SHARE_NAME));
            String max_price = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_MAX_PRICE));
            String min_price = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_MIN_PRICE));
            int action = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ACTION));
            Log.i("name", share_name + "/" + min_price + "/" + max_price);

            if (min_price.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                Log.i("min", "msg");
                double maxprice = Double.parseDouble(max_price);
                compareMax(share_name, maxprice, action);
            } else if (max_price.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                Log.i("max", "msg");
                double minprice = Double.parseDouble(min_price);
                compareMin(share_name, minprice, action);
            } else {
                Log.i("minmax", "msg");
                double maxprice = Double.parseDouble(max_price);
                double minprice = Double.parseDouble(min_price);
                compareMinMax(share_name, minprice, maxprice, action);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Problem is

when checking column values for `null`.For example for a row with values `(KEY_SHARE_NAME=name,KEY_MAX_PRICE=12,KEY_MIN_PRICE=null)`,the program raises a `null pointer exceptiuon at "else if (max_price.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))"` section.what am i doing wrong?I cant seem to point the exact issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*`"null"` and `null` are not the same. `"null"` is a String and read more about `null` at [What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java). So you can not do the `min_price.equalsIgnoreCase("null")` for null check. Read [How to check a string against null in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920525/how-to-check-a-string-against-null-in-java)*

---

Change

```
if (min_price.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                Log.i("min", "msg");
                double maxprice = Double.parseDouble(max_price);
                compareMax(share_name, maxprice, action);
            } else if (max_price.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                Log.i("max", "msg");
                double minprice = Double.parseDouble(min_price);
                compareMin(share_name, minprice, action);
            }
```

to

```
if (min_price == null) {
                Log.i("min", "msg");
                double maxprice = Double.parseDouble(max_price);
                compareMax(share_name, maxprice, action);
            } else if (max_price == null) {
                Log.i("max", "msg");
                double minprice = Double.parseDouble(min_price);
                compareMin(share_name, minprice, action);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

`null` and String `"null"` are not the same thing. Therefore for example this code:

```
min_price.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
```

should be changed to:

```
min_price == null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
min_price.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
```

will throw a NullPointerException if min_price is null.

Also, the above statement compares with "null", which is a string. You want to compare it with null reference.

Use `min_price == null` in that case